# php address request

Tags: php

i have this request method:

```
if (!$_REQUEST['0'])  {
    echo "Address missing...";
    die();
} else {
    code
    code etc.
}
```

And address is: http://localhost/api.php?0=*address*

If I open: `api.php?0=0` I should get another error which says address doesn't correct. But I get `Address missing`... In my opinion something wrong with:

```
if (!$_REQUEST['0'])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 0, null and false are treated the same by php. So when you put in 0=0 the condition sees it as false which is why you get "Adress doesn't provided".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking if $_REQUEST['0'] is false. In PHP (and many other languages), 0 stands for false. Because 0 == false, your expression results in 'true' and the `echo` and `die()` are executed.

If you are trying to test if $_REQUEST['0'] exists, you should use [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['0']))
{
    die("Address not provided");
}
else
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (empty ($_REQUEST['0'])) 
  {
      echo "Address doesn't provided...";
      die();
  } else {
     code
     code etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array_key_exists('0', $_REQUEST['0']) === true) {
    echo 'exists';
}
else {
    echo 'does not';
}
```

Sidenote: The best check to see if a key is set in an array is [array_key_exists](http://nl.php.net/array_key_exists). Opposed to isset, this function does not return false when the value is NULL.

Sidenote 2: You should specify which superglobal to use, using $_REQUEST instead of specifying $_POST or $_GET is can be the cause of vague errors to occur.